# How to combine values returned by getters on two classes without losing this context (as a single type)

Tags: typescript, this, getter-setter

I have three classes, `Chat`, `Quest` and `Receiver`.

It has three actions (methods) that are needed by another class, i.e. `Class Quest`. To avoid tightly coupling the two, I defined a getter (i.e. `chatInterface`) on class `Chat` to expose the three methods and pass them to class `Receiver`. I also used `bind` to avoid losing the `this` context.

Two of the actions (`actionB` and `actionC`) were moved to a third class, `Quest`. They're also exposed by a different getter in class `Quest`.

Is there a way I can combine the three methods (one method returned by class `Chat`, and 2 methods returned by class `Quest`), and pass them as a single type to class `Receiver`, without losing this context.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
type ChatInterface = {
  actionA(): void;
}

type QuestInterface = {
  actionB(): void;
  actionC(): void;
}

class Chat {
  readonly quest: Quest = new Quest();
  readonly receiver: Receiver = new Receiver(this.chatInterface, this.quest.questInterface);
  
  get chatInterface(): ChatInterface{
    return {
      actionA: this.actionA.bind(this),
    }
  }

  actionA() {

  }
}

class Quest{
  get questInterface(): QuestInterface{
    return {
      actionB: this.actionB.bind(this),
      actionC: this.actionC.bind(this),
    }
  }
  actionB() {
    
  }

  actionC() {
    
  }
}

class Receiver {
  constructor(private readonly chatInterface: ChatInterface, private readonly questInterface: QuestInterface){}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WG55oN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question and provided a minimal reproducible example. Could you please check it again to see if you can help this time?

Comment: You say "instead of passing them separately"; could you edit the example to show what that looks like so that it compiles? You can use an intersection type like `OneTwoInterFace & ThreeTwoInterFace`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W48O4W) but your example isn't showing how you plan to get the two sets of methods in one place, and inside of `One` for some reason you have `new Two(this.oneTwoInterface)`, which has no access to `ThreeTwoInterFace`. Can you resolve this for me?

Comment: I must admit that the naming here is also distracting; the  words `One`, `Two`, and `Three` give no indication of what they are or how they would depend on each other, especially not `Two` being dependent on `One` and `Three`.  And "interface" is a single word, so `InterFace` is as distracting as `InTerFace` or `InTeRfAcE` to me.   And if they're interfaces, why are you not defining them as `interface`s?  I'd suggest cleaning these up so that naming stuff doesn't pull attention away from your underlying issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did a poor job posting the question . I've cleaned it up now. Hope it's more readable. You're right, an intersection of the two types would be the type I need to use, but my problem is passing the actual instance of that intersection type to the class. When I mentioned "passing them separately," I meant something like this: `new Receiver(this.chatInterface, this.quest.questInterface);` Right now, that's the only way that I can think of to pass the two interfaces, but this doesn't work because the `this` in  `this.quest.questInterface;` gets unbound.

Comment: So, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/N54ePw) and it doesn't get unbound as far as I see, but I don't quite see how it's better than passing them separately.  Is that what you're looking for or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you got the gist of what I was trying to explain. I want `Receiver` to be able to access all 3 methods, but just receive 1 interface. The reason is mainly for readability and code organization. Currently, I have 1 interface and it's used in multiple places, so having 2 would mean making changes in many places. And I might have more interfaces down the road. Ideally, I wan to be able to combine the interfaces inside `Chat` class and then pass it as a single unit to `Receiver`. I think this `{ ...this.chatInterface, ...this.quest.questInterface }` is the closest to what I want.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  EDIT: hey, oops I see you've bound `this.actionB` twice instead of using `this.actionC`.  Can you fix that too?  Answer code will look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0oynN) and the logging will make more sense

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answers were very helpful. I think you've answered my question. I'll select it as the right answer once you've provided it. Thank you!!!

Comment: I notice you unaccepted my answer; can you explain what is missing from it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I think it happened accidentally. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single object type with all the properties from both object type `A` and object type `B` would [the intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `A` and `B`, which is expressed in TypeScript as `A & B`.

(Aside: things get tricky if `A` and `B` have overlapping or conflicting property keys, but this doesn't happen in your examples.  So it would be a digression to go into all the weird things that could happen, and I will ignore that possibility in what follows.)

Conceptually therefore all you'd have to do is take the `Receiver` constructor and collapse the two parameters of type `ChatInterface` and `QuestInterface` into a single parameter of type `ChatInterface & QuestInterface`:

```
class Receiver {
  constructor(private readonly chatAndQuest: ChatInterface & QuestInterface) {
  }
  callActions() {
    this.chatAndQuest.actionA()
    this.chatAndQuest.actionB()
    this.chatAndQuest.actionC()
  }
}
```

Of course that means you have to change the constructor call from `new Receiver(this.chatInterface, this.questInterface)` to something else.  The easiest way to do this would be to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) both `this.chatInterface` and `this.questInterface` into a new object:

```
    new Receiver({ ...this.chatInterface, ...this.quest.questInterface });
```

Normally you need to be careful when copying method-like properties from one object to another because of issues with [the `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  But in your case you've already used [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to fix the `this` context, so the particular object holding these methods no longer matters.

So this should work as expected.  If each `actionX` method calls `console.log("X", this)` where `X` is `A` or `B` or `C`, then you can verify that `Receiver` has everything it needs:

```
const c = new Chat();
c.receiver.callActions();

/* 
"A",  Chat: {
  "quest": {},
  "receiver": {
    "chatAndQuest": {}
  }
} 
"B",  Quest: {} 
"C",  Quest: {}  
*/
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQ2ASQHbAgJwGYIMbQC8UA3gLABQUU+wAlgPaoCCAFAJQBcUAbg3QBMA3JQC+lSqEhQAigFcIAZxTosuAlGLkqNPPSYAhDtz6CRO2o1QxjvfsLESKeADYJFi2ImBQ6AWzAXCD8IdE94JDQMHHxobWpMCAQBJhcQKABHBWVueSUfYlQIAHdZbOAOcwSklNQ0qESCOh4sbgAlCCaWzE1Kamoi0o6urFYSKAA6KeA4OkUJvG8otViAGknp2fms-Imd5WWYjVF2cz6oAHMIH0XI1SOIWwiVaPU48+rgOUxUUg-+yxMZjcGZzCaAlgTABGdFQAlYoMU7FW-3EOjR5whbHYfx01DwTEUDCCExcDAurAARMxKetEadzmiMc43B4yvlfAEgiEwuyDvc3rjqFcfPsXisCLY8vzXrEhf1El8fvL+rp9KgDCCtuC9FYDNDYfD6Si8QDdUwYFqwRCYAa4QitsjUYzMeaNRwVVACagiSSyRTKQZaVB6VUoMzqDaPfF+t7fRBSeSqTBg6GXRRma53J5hhBmlh5XHgJg5HoGJhWGBMM0kNBEslUulbsBmHDpcBuM9DoKAGR88UPHExtH4hAuFzMN2KaP-RELbytgTtnXq7Gz7XNxfLiFGdjrsGbtvlFdWGx79GOCiUItezRQQZeJCVa8TRp57oLMcTqccJwAegAKigShqWDR8O3lSkxUpbgSFEE1qEpN980wGDPUpQ8l3KNC4PTURgIoQMwPbWD8JAlN1n7UjqEoAC-ycIA)